# Rename some Rigify layer names

Tags: rigify

I merged two *Rigify* Armatures which has caused some bone Layers name loss.   Is there some way to edit these groups to provide new names? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buttons for the bone layer selection are created by a script. It's generated by the <kbd>Generate Rig</kbd> button. The default name is "rig_ui.py" and it contains a unique rig ID. The name can be changed in the *Advanced* section where the *Generate Rig* button is. There can be more than one script if you have 2 or more Rigify rigs in the scene.

Go to the *Scripting* workspace, and look for *"rig_ui.py"* **(1)**. Then scroll almost to the end, and you will (*hopefully*) see the code lines that create the buttons in the side panel **(2)**. Change it and run the script **(3)**. It should update immediately.

[image]

Comment: Just open the hood, reach back beyond the carburetor, and find the hidden fuse box!  ;-)